# Remove certain values anywhere form url

Tags: php

I want to know whether or not it is possible to remove any values from a url that is going to be passed. For instance `www.example.com/dummypage1/en/var?123` now what I want to do is remove the `en` in the url, which will now look like `www.example.com/dummypage1/var?123`

Comment: `en` is not a variable that is passed through the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this answer:

```
$url= "www.example.com/dummypage1/en/var?123";

$piece=explode('en/',$url);    // en/ is the word you want to remove..

$newurl=$piece[0].$piece[1];
echo $newurl;
```

echo:
www.example.com/dummypage1/var?123

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `parse_url()`, `explode()` and `implode()`.

You'll be able to do it using those three.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode:

```
$url = "www.example.com/dummypage1/en/var?123 ";
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$end = array_slice($parts, 3);
$parts = array_merge(array_slice($parts, 0, 2), $end);
$url = implode('/', $parts);
```

Comment: it doenst seem to work i am getting errors at line 4 and 5 or in the above code line 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

Simply by using `str_replace()`, Remove desired word in your case `en/` by replacing it with an empty string:

```php
$url = "www.example.com/dummypage1/en/var?123";
echo str_replace('en/', '', $url);
```

***Output**:`www.example.com/dummypage1/var?123`*